# Django filter with a lot of values ok PK

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-haystack

I do:

```
qs = qs.filter(pk__in=qs_searches)
```

with qs a (15000) *QuerySet* and sq_searches a big (+1000) *haystack.query.ValuesListSearchQuerySet*

It takes a lot of time.

More info:

- Indexation backend is Whoosh
- DB is currently sqlite
- pk has db_index=True (maybe useless)

Is it possible to optimize it?

Comment: You need join relationships.

Comment: Could you give me  an example  plz?